# HTML/CSS: strange scroll bar appears next to my images

Tags: css, scrollbar

On [this page](http://secretcitywalks.co/wp/), underneath "Select your city [arrow down]", there are two grey rectangles.

In Google Chrome, there is a scroll bar to the right of the rectangles.

What is causing this scroll bar, and how do I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of  `overflow: auto;` in your `#walk-categories` css style. Remove it or change it to `hidden`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following css property of the div with id `walk-categories`,

```
overflow: auto;
```

in the css class `#walk-categories`

Answer (score 0):

your `walk-categories` has its `overflow` set to `auto` in it's style which means a scroll bar will appear if the div's content is bigger than the size of the div itself.

make the content smaller or change `walk-categories`'s  overflow to `hidden`

Answer (score 0):

the scrollbar is due to your `overflow: auto;` in the css at this place:

```
 media="all"
 #walk-categories, #walk-testimonials {
    margin: 14px 0;
    margin: 1rem 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

remplace `overflow: auto;` by `overflow: hidden;` and it will be ok ;)

hope i help